# Make only bullets clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a menu that is designed using an unordered list, with each list element containing a link to another page. However, I would also like to be able to click on each bullet point to open more subcategories that will also link to other pages.

Essentially, I would like to be able to click once on a link and have it go to the correct page, but I would also like to click on the bullet point and have it expand into the subcategories. I've been researching how to separate the bullet from the content of the li, but it doesn't seem to be working in my case, likely because my li contains a lot of subcategories. Here's an example:

```
<li id="m2l1" class="child">
    <a href="#">Y</a>
        <ul id="u11">
            <li class="gchild"><a href="#">Y.1</a></li>
            <li class="gchild"><a href="#">Y.2</a></li>
            <li class="gchild"><a href="#">Y.3</a></li>
            <li class="gchild"><a href="#">Y.4</a></li>
            <li class="gchild"><a href="#">Y.5</a></li>
            <li class="gchild"><a href="#">Y.6</a></li>
            <li class="gchild"><a href="#">Y.7</a></li>
            <li class="gchild"><a href="#">Y.8</a></li>
            <li class="gchild"><a href="#">Y.9</a></li>
        </ul>
</li>
```

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to separate the  bullet from the text in my case?

Here's the link: http://jsfiddle.net/stamblerre/XYp48/17/

Thank you!!!

Comment: @Satpal Can't open subcategories because it closes parent category ;)

Comment: @user3737684 You can set an event handler on the `<li>`, and ensure that `event.target === this` to make sure you're clicking on the list itself and not anything inside the list.

Comment: Just as an info, the html in your fiddle is invalid. You can not have anything except a `<li>` as direct child of an `<ul>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your HTML is invalid. You can't have `div` inside your `ul`. Moreover, you can greatly simplify your code by moving separate logic for each `li` into one generic handler.

Something like this:

***Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/XYp48/18/***

*CSS*:

```
ul {
    display: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}
ul:first-child {
    display: block;
}
```

*JS*:

```
$("li").on("click", function () {
    $(this).children("ul").slideToggle();
    return false;
});
```

**Edit**:

I deliberately left out checking of `a` because clicking the `a` would navigate to the respective pages (as mentioned in your question), so expand/collapse wouldn't matter.

However, as per your comment if you really want to remove `a` altogether from the handler, then you can use the event target to handle `li` without `a`. Something like this:

***Demo 2: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/XYp48/22/***

*JS*:

```
$("li").on("click", function (e) {
    var $t = $(e.target); // get the event target as a jQuery object
    if (!$t.is('a')) { // check if the target is not an anchor
        $(this).children("ul").slideToggle();
        return false;
    }
    // otherwise if target is anchor, then do nothing
});
```

Comment: thanks very much for your help - i will definitely work on restructuring my code and using your suggestions. one question however: in the demo you sent, it seems like clicking on the links themselves still causes the subcategories to open up. any idea on why that might be?

Answer (score 4):

Change your list still to hide bullets, then modify your html to :

```
<li class="gchild"><a href="#">&bull;</a>Y.1</li>
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: that would work, but unfortunately my actual code has a custom bullet image that is added in through the background-image attribute. thanks though!

Comment: Remove @blue112's &bull;, add a class to the `<a href="#">` tag, and use that to hold your custom bullet image instead of the li.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#"><li class="gchild">Y.1</li></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way that worked for me: remove the bullet with `li { list-style-type: none; }` then add your own bullets with the character • (alt-8 on a mac). Add that character inside `a` elements like so:

```
<a href="">•</a> X
```

with the label now outside of the element.

Hope this works for you!